# Increase Number Button in Guizero (Simple)

Tags: function, user-interface, button, assignment-operator, guizero

I am working on something for my classroom where students can use a voting system by clicking a touch screen. I am new to Python and searched through a few answers, but I couldn't find what I am looking for.

I am trying to create a button that increases a number each time it is pressed. However, it only allows me to click the button once, and then it displays the number. I could be understanding guizero wrong, but I thought it was basically a while loop that constantly checks user input.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

```
from guizero import App, Text, PushButton

def increase_number(x):
    x += 1
    display_number.value = x


number = 10
app=App()
display_number = Text(app)
button = PushButton(app, text="Press me", command=lambda:increase_number(number))

app.display()
```

I used the lambda function as someone on here mentioned that is how a button needs to work if you want the function to run after you click the button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The x/current votes value needs to be a global otherwise it will just reset the vote value every time you press the button.

```
from guizero import App, Text, PushButton

app = App()

#Stater number
x=0

def increase_number():
    global x
    x += 1
    display_number.value = x


display_number = Text(app,text=x)
button = PushButton(app, text="Press me", command=increase_number)


app.display()
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks. Why does it not need the lambda present? Also, you used the function "increase_number" without the parenthesis. How does this change how it is used?

Comment: If you check out the Guizero documentation command run a little differently. Guizero also has lots of example you might want to check out. Here is a good example that will show you how functions and command work https://github.com/lawsie/guizero/blob/master/examples/hide_show_test.py